# Is it possible to decouple XMLSchema from an XMLType column?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a table with an XMLTYPE column which is mapped to an XMLSCHEMA url.
But now we want to decouple the xmltype column from the xml schema and store the xml data into the column with out any validation.
Table is not empty and the existing data in xmltype column should be retained.
Can any one please suggest, if it is possible to achieve this by using ALTER TABLE command.

Ex Table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE 
( ID NUMBER,
  DESC VARCHAR2(500),
  XMLWRAPPER XMLTYPE
) XMLTYPE COLUMN XMLWRAPPER XMLSCHEMA "TESTXSD" ELEMENT "data"
TABLESPACE TEST_DATA01;
```

Comment: I tried several ways like `ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE ( XMLWRAPPER  ALLOW NONXMLSCHEMA DISALLOW ANYSCHEMA );` but none of them worked. Perhaps you have to add a new column and move all data to this new column.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have referred to alter table documentation and tried to alter using below alter statement, but no luck :(

ALTER TABLE test_table MODIFY(xmlwrapper REMOVE XMLSCHEMAS(XMLSCHEMA "TESTXSD" ELEMENT "data"));

Alter table documentation URL: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2103924

Comment: From the docs (not tested) "When you remove an XMLSchema, the table is scanned and any XMLType rows encoded using that particular schema are deleted." Probably not what you wanted.